# Why is my Windows 7 system stuck at a configuration screen?

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a Gateway touch screen system running Windows 7 Home Premium.

When starting up, Windows configuration fails and begins trying to revert. It never happens. I've tried System Restore, and that worked a couple times, but now I can't do that. I've tried System Recovery as well and I get this screen that is grey in color with a drop down box to select a language which is greyed out and select keyboard input method which is blue with US highlighted.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what happens, including any messages? I'm probably not the only one who doesn't know what you mean by "When starting up windows configurayion fsils and begins trying to revert. It never happens", i.e. trying to "revert" how? What "never happens"?  That will make it more likely that someone can help you. Also this is not such a panic that it needs the "Help" & 11 exclamation points;  everyone posting a question here needs help.

Comment: Sorry about mispelled  words. I meant whenever windows begins starting up it says" performing configuration please do not turn your computer off". Then after about 10 minutes its says " windows configuration failure reverting changes please do not turn your computer off. It stays hung thereafter.As I said I've tried system restore which worked a couple of times but can't do it now.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's clearer. You might want to clean up your question and include the additional info. The screen that you see re. "configuration" is usually after updates have been applied.  Unfortunately, if you turned it off during updates, you might have to repair the Windows installation.  Did you try starting in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, it boots without problems in safemode. How can I repair the  windows installation? PC did not come with a installation disk.

Answer (score 2):

boot from the [Windows 7 DVD or Windows Recovery Environment (F8)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-are-the-system-recovery-options-in-Windows-7) and run the command prompt and run this:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

(replace C: with the drive where you installed Windows 7)

This reverts all pending operations. After booting to Windows share the log files from C:\Windows\logs\CBS, so that I can see why Windows updates fail.

Comment: I am used to DISM for other purposes, and just wondered if you know whether or not this can be initiated from within Windows, i.e. from Safe Mode.

Comment: inside Windows you must replace /Image:C\ with /Online But I have no idea if this works.

Comment: Okay I tried this in command prompt. It said unable to access the image.Make sure that the image path and the windows directory for the image exist and you have permissions on the folder.

Comment: have you used it inside Windows with /Online or outside of Windows with /Image?